# SSH + RSA скрипт копирования файлов

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsa

Помогите примером скрипта bash под linux ubuntu, задача по sftp ssh копировать файлы из папки локального диска в папку удаленного подключения, требуется использовать RSA файл для регистрации подключения. Как сделать подобный скрипт, чтобы добавить его в cron?

Comment: Что по подобное? Или есть проще, лучше? - scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub FILENAME USER@SERVER:/home/USER/FILENAME

Comment: Еще момент, может WinSCP можно сделать автоматизацию копирования?

Comment: у вас несколько никак не связанных друг с другом вопросов. декомпилируйте их, пожалуйста, затем определитесь, что именно не получается сделать на том или ином шаге, и задайте отдельные **конкретные** вопросы (с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы).

Comment: для копирования ключа используйте ssh-copy-id. потом используйте rsync для копирования.

Comment: если вы хотите автоматическую авторизацию на удаленном хосте без ручных действий, то настраивайте керберос. но ручные телодвижения всеравно нужны чтобы получить ключи от KDC, так что быстрее использовать ssh-copy-id.

Comment: Вот эта команда подойдет? scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub FILENAME USER@SERVER:/home/USER/FILENAME Мне нужно копировать на SFTP по SSH файлы с использованием уже готового ключа RSA.

Comment: Поясню. Ключ RSA уже зарегистрирован на удаленном сервере, нам нужно лишь использовать его в команде для аутентификации и передачи файлов из папки А в папку Б. Как правильно написать команду, подойдет ли это? Спасибо! scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub FILENAME USER@SERVER:/home/USER/FILENAME

Comment: Не получилось этой командой: scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub FILENAME USER@SERVER:/home/USER/FILENAME

Требует пароль 8-(